# Automatiing Blob Trigger on Logic App with ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have the following (partial) template. The template also creates a storage account with and a blob container.

The question is, how do I obtain the folderId?

I have tried with resourceId of the blob container but either I'm doing something wrong or I'm going down the wrong track as it's not working.

The JTJmZ2kgx2RhdFE= value was added when I manually created the Logic App.

Any ideas?

```
"triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['blob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "JTJmZ2kgx2RhdFE=",
                        "maxFileCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmZ2kgx2RhdFE=": "/data",
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am an idiot, it's just the name encoded as base64. I could've sworn that I had checked that it was base64. best go to bed really

Comment: please provide the answer in such case so that it can help others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:  base64 encoding of the name.  However the / is url encoded so it's base64 of **%2Fdata**

Answer (score -1):

Modification: use "f" instead of "F"
base64(%2**f**data)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it